# How to make screen terminal emulation act more like xterm or rxvt for init/uninit

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

Programs like `less` and full-screen editors work well with terminals like `xterm` and `rxvt`, because the terminal initialization and uninitialization lets the terminal save current screen contents and restore it after the program exits.

I'm wondering if `screen` can be configured to act in the same way.

Concrete example:

Let's say I create a simple file `foo` containing some lines:

```
for ((i=0;i<10;++i)); do echo $i; done > foo
```

Now, I use `less` to view its contents, and immediately quit out of `less` with `q`. In `screen`, the console now looks like this:

```
~$ for ((i=0;i<10;++i)); do echo $i; done > foo
~$ less foo
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
~$
```

If I do the same thing outside a `screen` environment, and in a plain `rxvt` terminal window instead, I get this:

```
~$ for ((i=0;i<10;++i)); do echo $i; done > foo
~$ less foo
~$
```

The terminal has saved the screen contents and restored them.

Is there anything I can configure in `screen` to do this, or any entries I should add to termcap or terminfo to support this?

Here's the relevant section in termcap (my TERM=screen):

```
SC|screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal:\
        :am:xn:ms:mi:G0:km:\
        :DO=\E[%dB:LE=\E[%dD:RI=\E[%dC:UP=\E[%dA:bs:bt=\E[Z:\
        :cb=\E[1K:cd=\E[J:ce=\E[K:cl=\E[H\E[J:cm=\E[%i%d;%dH:ct=\E[3g:\
        :do=^J:nd=\E[C:pt:rc=\E8:rs=\Ec:sc=\E7:st=\EH:up=\EM:\
        :le=^H:bl=^G:cr=^M:it#8:ho=\E[H:nw=\EE:ta=^I:is=\E)0:\
        :li#24:co#80:us=\E[4m:ue=\E[24m:so=\E[3m:se=\E[23m:\
        :mb=\E[5m:md=\E[1m:mr=\E[7m:me=\E[m:sr=\EM:al=\E[L:\
        :AL=\E[%dL:dl=\E[M:DL=\E[%dM:cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:dc=\E[P:\
        :DC=\E[%dP:im=\E[4h:ei=\E[4l:IC=\E[%d@:\
        :ks=\E[?1h\E=:ke=\E[?1l\E>:vb=\Eg:\
        :ku=\EOA:kd=\EOB:kr=\EOC:kl=\EOD:kb=^H:\
        :k1=\EOP:k2=\EOQ:k3=\EOR:k4=\EOS:k5=\E[15~:k6=\E[17~:\
        :k7=\E[18~:k8=\E[19~:k9=\E[20~:k;=\E[21~:F1=\E[23~:F2=\E[24~:\
        :kh=\E[1~:kI=\E[2~:kD=\E[3~:kH=\E[4~:@7=\E[4~:kP=\E[5~:\
        :kN=\E[6~:eA=\E(B\E)0:as=^N:ae=^O:\
        :vi=\E[?25l:ve=\E[34h\E[?25h:vs=\E[34l:\
        :Co#8:pa#64:AF=\E[3%dm:AB=\E[4%dm:op=\E[39;49m:AX:\
        :ac=``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~..--++,,hhII00:
```

And from terminfo, according to `infocmp`:

```
screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual terminal,
        am, km, mir, msgr, xenl,
        colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
        acsc=++\,\,--..00II``aaffgghhjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
        clear=\E[H\E[J, cnorm=\E[34h\E[?25h, cr=^M,
        csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\EM,
        cvvis=\E[34l, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
        dl1=\E[M, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K, enacs=\E(B\E)0,
        flash=\Eg, home=\E[H, ht=^I, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@,
        il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=^J, is2=\E)0, kbs=\177,
        kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
        kdch1=\E[3~, kend=\E[4~, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
        kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf2=\EOQ, kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS,
        kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~,
        khome=\E[1~, kich1=\E[2~, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~, nel=\EE,
        op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rmacs=^O,
        rmcup=\E[?1049l, rmir=\E[4l, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, rmso=\E[23m,
        rmul=\E[24m, rs2=\Ec, sc=\E7, setab=\E[4%p1%dm,
        setaf=\E[3%p1%dm, sgr0=\E[m, smacs=^N, smcup=\E[?1049h,
        smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[3m, smul=\E[4m,
        tbc=\E[3g,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question on Hacker News, and received this answer:

> try "altscreen on".

Putting this line into my `~/.screenrc` worked well to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your example, and get the same behaviour within a screen session as in the terminal (i.e. the contents of foo aren't displayed), using Gnome Terminal or xterm.

Versions: 
GNOME Terminal 2.26.0 
Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06  
XTerm(241)

Comment: I'm running rxvt from Cygwin on Windows and screen on Nexenta (Solaris with GNU userland). I'll see what's the story with term* entries...